# Find difference between two Data Objects using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 data objects. Employee and Manager

```
class Employee{
int EmpId;
int EmpName }

Class Manager{
int ManagerID; //is the empId of an employee who is Manager
}
```

I want a list of EmpName who is not a Manager using LINQ in a single statement.

I tried this:

```
var employeeIdsWhoAreNotManagers = EmployeeList.Select(x=>x.EmpId).Except(Managerlist.Select(x=>x.ManagerId));
```

but this returns me only EmpId. Then again i have to write one more linq to get the EmpName .

**Update1:**

```
 empNamesList = EmployeeList.Where(x=>x.employeeIdsWhoAreNotManagers.Contains(x.empId)).Select(x=>x.empName);
```

How do I Combine into a single LINQ query which results me the EmpName list directly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is Linq to object, you can use an extension method `ExceptBy`

```
public static IEnumerable<T1> ExceptBy<T1, T2, R>(
    this IEnumerable<T1> source, 
    IEnumerable<T2> other, 
    Func<T1,R> keySelector1, 
    Func<T2,R> keySelector2)
{
    HashSet<R> set = new HashSet<R>(other.Select(x => keySelector2(x)));

    return source.Where(item => set.Add(keySelector1(item)));
}
```

.

```
 EmployeeList.ExceptBy(Managerlist, x=>x.EmpId , y=>y.ManagerId));
```